# Easiest way to translate live GPS to realtime GTFS?

Tags: gps, general-transit-feed-specification

I have live GPS data coming in from the city's buses and given that I already have the routes in GTFS ( https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/ ) I would like to convert this data to the GTFS format.

Is there a way to convert a bus's GPS coordinates taken at a certain time into a stop_sequence and delay, if there is any?

EDIT: I've found https://github.com/cbick/gps2gtfs but it requires some tweaking from what I understand, it's not a finished library.

Comment: It's a bit broad a question. Can you narrow it down to a particular software or development language? Otherwise I fear this question will get closed.

Comment: Are you asking if you can produce a GTFS stop_times.txt file (and specifically write the stop_sequence attribute on the fly based on the buses current postion?